# Find the top scorer in a league

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am new to databases. I have been given an assignment which is something to do with football league where some teams play home and away and the scores are stored etc etc. I have the following tables

```
goals
======================
goal_id 
goal_player_people_id
goal_game_id
goal_score

player
=====================
player_people_id
player_team_id

people
====================
people_id
people_first_name
people_last_name
people_dob
```

I need to find out the name of the top scorer, please help.

Comment: Are you tables really named that long?

Comment: It's column names , not table names.

Comment: This is a pretty trivial query. What have you tried?

Comment: JOIN goals to players and people, sort by goal_score return 1

Comment: I think, it would be like 
    select max(count(field)) from table where ....

Comment: Does your goal_player_people_id, player_people_id and people_id have same value?

Answer (score 1):

if `goals.goal_player_people_id` is a reference to `people.people_id`:

```
SELECT p.people_first_name, p.people_last_name, SUM(g.goal_score) totscore
FROM goals g
JOIN people p
ON g.goal_player_people_id = p.people_id
GROUP BY p.people_id
ORDER BY totscore DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  people_first_name people_last_name
from people
where people_id not in(
    select A.id
    from(
        select goal_player_people_id as id,count(*) as gc
        form goals
        group by goal_player_people_id) A,
        (
        select goal_player_people_id as id,count(*) as gc
        form goals
        group by goal_player_people_id) B,
    where A.gc<B.gc
)
```